# How to declare two unassignable types?

Tags: typescript

I have a FFI binding and there are a couple of places where `void *` is used. I'd like to differentiate those on Typescript side. What I do is:

```
interface Struct1Ptr extends Buffer {};
interface Struct2Ptr extends Buffer {};
var x: Struct1Ptr;
var y: Struct2Ptr;
```

I'd like to make those types unassignable, so that error is signaled when I try to assign `x = y` or `y = x` or use wrong type as arguments to functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript uses structural typing for everything, so you actually have to make them structurally different, e.g :

```
interface Struct1Ptr extends Buffer { _isStruct1: void };
interface Struct2Ptr extends Buffer { _isStruct2: void };
var x: Struct1Ptr;
var y: Struct2Ptr;
```

Comment: Now it is not assignable to base class, which may or may not be a good thing.

Comment: If someone requests a Buffer, Struct1Ptr and Struct2Ptr are assignable to it. The opposite is not true of course. Pretty much expected, no?

Comment: Pretty much, although I also need a concept of `NULL` that is assignable to both `x` and `y` and there is `ref.NULL` of type `Buffer`. It basically is a try to simulate C language semantics in Typescript.